# Rolling Ruby version back is causing problems

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

```
Mac OS
```

I was working with Ruby 2.7.0 and Rails 6, but a few gems, as well as dependencies, are not Ruby 2.7.0 compliant, and was getting a ton of warning messages. So, I decided to un-install Ruby 2.7.0

```
rbenv uninstall 2.7.0

rbenv install 2.6.3
```

Now, whenever I try to do anything, I get the following error message:

```
ruby: invalid option -:  (-h will show valid options) (RuntimeError)
```

Even if I'm doing something as simple as:

```
ruby -v
```

From my terminal:

```
unset RUBYOPT
```

Everything works fine, until the next time I go into terminal. While I may be able to work around it, on my development machine, from terminal, my IDE doesn't understand this, and generated the same error, whenever I do Rake, from the IDE.

When I set rbenv up, it inserted the following, into my .bash_profile:

```
export RUBYOPT='-W:no-deprecated -W:no-experimental'
if which rbenv > /dev/null; then eval "$(rbenv init -)"; fi
```

Any ideas?

## Solution:

I removed the following statement, that was added by rbenv to my .bash_profile:

```
export RUBYOPT='-W:no-deprecated -W:no-experimental'
```

and it's working fine now

Comment: Are you setting RUBYOPT somewhere in your shell initialization like in your `~/.bash_profile` or `~/.profile`?

Comment: Yes, it looks like rbenv inserted a couple of lines into .bash_profile, see edit to my question

Comment: You should be able to just comment out that line. `'-W:no-deprecated -W:no-experimental'` just silences a bunch of depreciation messages.

Comment: Also in OS-X GUI programs like your IDE don't get their ENV vars from your shell. `unset RUBYOPT` just effects that shell. Not the whole OS. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/135688/setting-environment-variables-on-os-x

Comment: It does kind of sound like either a bug in rbenv or something else on your system thats modifying RUBYOPT. When you launch a shell does `echo $RUBYOPT` output `-`?

Comment: Isn't '-W:no-deprecated -W:no-experimental' what's preventing the deprecation messages? I don't get deprecation messages on my local system, I get them on the server, but that's not really what my question is. It's about resetting RUBYOPT once and for all.

Comment: When I echo $RUBYOPT, I get: -W:no-deprecated -W:no-experimental, which is the setting in .bash_profile

Comment: Tip: You don't need to uninstall Ruby, you can just switch versions. That's what `rbenv` is all about.